# How to get the length of an array of objects in MySQL Json column where the containing objects met a condition

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to query a Mysql json column that contains an array of objects. I want the length of the array where a condition is met in the objects

Example of the JSON array:

```
[
    {"userId": 100, "type": 1, "status": 1},
    {"userId": 101, "type": 2, "status": 1},
]
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(json_users), 0) AS my_count, post_id 
FROM posts WHERE post_id = 6421028173277829027 
AND json_contains(json_users, '{"type" : 1, "status": 1}');
```

This will return the following whic is desired

```
+------------+---------------------+
| my_count   | post_id             |
+------------+---------------------+
|          1 | 6421028173277829027 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

But if I change the query where param 'type' to say 3

```
SELECT IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(json_users), 0) AS my_count, post_id 
FROM posts WHERE post_id = 6421028173277829027 
AND json_contains(json_users, '{"type" : 3, "status": 1}');
```

I get an empty set. But I'm trying to get the following:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| my_count   | post_id             |
+------------+---------------------+
|          0 | 6421028173277829027 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

I assume I have to change the where clause and somehow check inside the following:

```
IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(## json_users ##), 0)
```

but I don't know where to start

**EDIT:**

The following query returns an array of paths to the objects so I can use JSON_LENGTH to get the count:

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(IFNULL(JSON_SEARCH(json_users->>'$[*].type', 'all', 1), JSON_ARRAY())) AS my_count
FROM posts WHERE post_id = 6421028173277829027;
```

Answer (score 23):

Did you try

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(json_users, "$.type")) FROM posts
```

I know there is a bug where if `json_users` is null, it will not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Jeremy R DeYoung's answer, if you want to have a lack of the JSON field show as a length of 0 just use COALESCE eg:

```
COALESCE(JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(json_users, "$.type")),0)
```